# Several types prices for same product

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, catalog-price-rules, downloadable

I`m building digital store in Magento 1.9. Site is selling the same downloadable products but with different prices depending on what license our client want to buy.

Let me clarify what I need:

We have several types of licenses: for personal use, for advertising, for TV etc. Respectively the prices are changed when client chooses the type of usage of our downloadable product. If user selects "for personal use" the whole catalog have to show the price for "personal use".

How to change whole catalog prices on the fly?
The best example of what I need I found in audionetwork.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest group prices. With this feature you can define prices per customer group.

You will need to implement something to let the customer switch his group on the fly per dropdown, but even if you want to do this for not logged in customers, it will be less work and more stable than creating your own price logic. Also, group prices take full advantage of the Magento indexes.